# Can mushrooms be re-heated safely?

Tags: food-safety, reheating, mushrooms

What happens inside mushrooms when you reheat them?

Is it always unsafe to reheat them or is there something you can do to safely reheat them?

Comment: What's a champion? I can't find any mention on Wikipedia of a food item called a champion.

Comment: Voting to close as too localized, because nobody seems to know what this is about and there's been no response to comments for close to 4 hours.

Comment: Oh, sorry for getting the English term wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In France, white button mushrooms are called champignons.  Before refrigeration was common, books suggested [not to keep cooked mushrooms or reheat them](http://www.eufic.org/page/en/faqid/why-not-reheat-mushrooms/), because undercooked mushrooms would quickly spoil.  If you cooked them and later keep them in the refrigerator, it is safe to reheat mushrooms.  Treat mushrooms as you would treat meat.

Mushrooms are mainly water, so they reheat well in the microwave.  Do it on low power. Depending on the cooking technique, the texture may change by using high power.

Comment: Small detail: In France, all mushrooms can be called “champignons”. If you need to be specific, white button mushrooms are called “champignons de Paris”. It's in Germany that white button mushrooms are called simply “champignons”.

Answer (score 5):

It depends *very much* on which mushrooms. For button mushrooms, see papin's answer; this does not however hold for wild mushrooms.

In particular, some wild mushrooms (in particular those called "le champignon bleu" in French, I never found out what they were in English) may cause serious poisoning if eaten 24 hours after cooking. Believe me, I know. Apparently they contain a protein which changes after cooking, and one day is enough for it to become poisonous.

Comment: I know this is a long shot since your answer is over a decade old at this point, but do you have any more supporting information for this? It would be quite helpful to advance the advice beyond conventional "wives' tale" wisdom.